# How to move navigation bar after user stops scrolling with delay (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, scroll, navigation

I am new to JavaScript and have the following code which hides a navigation bar when the user scrolls.

```
// When the user scrolls down 40px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scroll > 40 || document.documentElement.scroll > 40) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "144px";
  }
}
```

I am attempting to have the navigation bar disappear after the user stops scrolling (after a short delay), and then show again when the user starts scrolling again.

I have tried various things including looping the function with setInterval(function, delay)
and using window.addEventListener to wait for scrolling but nothing seems to be working for me.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction with how to set this up?

Many thanks in advance with any help,
Elya

Comment: Does this `document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";` hides your navbar?

Comment: @Dahou Yes, it hides the Navbar by moving it behind another element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` when handling the scroll event to hide the navbar after a delay

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

let hideTimer = 0;

function scrollFunction() {
  // show navbar whenever the user scroll
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "144px";

  // clear the previously schduled hiding (if it exist)
  hideTimer && clearTimeout(hideTimer);

  // Schedule hiding (delaying)
  hideTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  }, 500); // delayed by 0.5 second
}
```

I haven't test it, but it should do the trick!